# How to trigger some code on a select tag either on change or on keyup but not when select loses focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

(using jQuery 1.4.4 edition)

The title of the question might not be that clear, that is why I am going into a more detailed description below:

I am trying to trigger some JavaScript code when a selection in one of my select boxes changes. I know that I can do that with the `change()` as follows:

```
var my_handler = function(eventObject){
  // ... do something here ...
};
$('#my_select_box').change(my_handler);
```

The problem is that this is not triggered when user changes selection by keyboard. I searched in Stack Overflow and everybody is suggesting to bind the same handler on `keyup` event too, as follows:

```
var my_handler = function(eventObject){
  // ... do something here ...
};
$('#my_select_box').change(my_handler).keyup(my_handler);
```

Indeed, both when I change the selection by keyboard and when I change the selection by mouse the handler is executed.

The problem is when I change the selection with keyboard and then I move on to the next field (either by mouse or keyboard) in the form. The handler is triggered again (second time)

Can you explain why does this happen and tell me whether there is a way to bypass this problem?

Comment: I think you don't need to use bind the `keyup` and `change` just `change` is working fine for me.
http://jsfiddle.net/99YCX/1/

Comment: @TheSuperTramp This is what I do for now, since the combination of `change` and `keyup` does not work the way I want. The point is that when the user uses the keyboard I do not have my handler called, which is something I want. I want everytime the user changes his choice either by keyboard or mouse to call my handler. The combination of binding to these two events is almost optimal. But, it has the problem that I am describing when the user takes the next two actions in sequence: 1) change with keyboard 2) leave focus. The 1st action triggers the event and the 2nd action triggers it too.Boom.

Comment: Please visit [this](http://jsfiddle.net/99YCX/1/) page and change the selection of the first select box(either by keyboard or mouse) and see if the handler is called(logged in red). P.S. I used firefox 7.0.1

Comment: @TheSuperTramp Ok. I just went there. The problem is that in the page you have there, you have a select box with `size` attribute on select tag. If you remove this, then behavior is as I describe it. Do you want to try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only answer that seems to work is to keep track of the actual change of your value in some way, like a variable outside the event handler. You may not be able to avoid raising the event, but you can choose not to respond to it. The example below illustrates:

```
var lastVal = null;
var my_handler = function(eventObject) {
    if (lastVal == $(this).val()) return;
    console.log("Changed");
    lastVal = $(this).val();
    eventObject.stopPropagation();
};

$('#my_select_box').change(my_handler).keyup(my_handler);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the **keypress** event: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html

Or You can **ignore** the key events you don't want: http://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html

Comment: `keypress`...tried that. Works the same. The problem is the following sequence of actions 1) change with keyboard 2) leave focus. The 1st action triggers the event and the 2nd action triggers it too.

Comment: the first triggers the keyup event and leaving focus triggers the change event. this I think is expected behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirement a not so ideal solution would be a key up on the select and a click on the options as per [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/circadian/dYrVz/)

```
$("#my_select_box option").bind("click", function(e) {
    my_handler();

});

$("#my_select_box").bind("keyup", function(e) {
    my_handler();

});
```

Comment: I went to your jsfiddle page and I changed from Volvo to Saab and nothing was printed.